# Spring Cloud Gateway Guide from Pivotal not working well

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need help learning and running Spring Cloud Gateway.
I have been following this [Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/) from Pivotal as faithfully as I can, but I keep on getting problems. Here's my progress so far on [Github](https://github.com/khalilsleimi/gateway). I even thought I was doing things the right way that I started to make [pull requests](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-gateway/pull/14) to their own guide as fixes, but I think there's something I'm missing somewhere. Any help or guidance is going to be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should use Spring Cloud 2020.0.3 not 2020.0.4. Reverting back solved it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, I believe, is that Spring Cloud 2020.0.4 was used, but after using Spring Cloud 2020.0.3 everything was fixed.